# PHP SQLite info within an ini file

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have an INI file that I parse into the title that I include into every page.

Now I can set parameters for a normal database and use them as so:

```
host = localhost:3306;
dbname = db;
user = user;
password = pword;
```

and I am able to call these within my code.

Now I am trying to change over to SQLite as will be a big help to my site and I keep getting errors and I think it may be to do with the INI file.
I have:

```
host = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . 'sqlite:/Data/DB/CheekyIT.sqlite';
dbname = DB;
password = pword;
```

then call:

```
$dbh  = new pdo($CheekyIT['host']) or die("cannot open the database");

$query =  "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE Area='AYL'";

foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row)
{
    echo $row[0];
}
```

and nothing works.

Either it can't find the file or the driver can't be found and I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\wamp64\www\"File location of current page"
```

and within the php.ini file the appropriate extensions have been enabled.

Comment: why can't you use simple php files for config?

Comment: May sound silly, but what do you mean. I have my ini file that works with a local db and an external, its just with the sqlite that dosent work :/.

Comment: I suspect that you cant use php variables and operations in an ini file

Comment: Oh,  sorry. Did not read the error message, because you had managed to hide it. You dont have PDO driver for it. You need to either install or uncomment in php.ini the `pdo_sqlite` module.

Comment: Well this is how it is working: CheekyIT.ini: host = localhost:3306; dbname = CheekyIT; user = 'Cheeky IT'; password = password. then you call the ini file: $cheekyitDB = parse_ini_file($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/Data/LIB/Config/CheekyITDBSQLite.ini');. this is in the page that will be affected. then I call $servername = $cheekyitDB['host'];
        $username = $cheekyitDB['user'];
        $password = $cheekyitDB['password'];
        $dbname = $cheekyitDB['dbname'];
            
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);.

Comment: I have already taken the ; from the ini: ;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

Comment: ...and you shouldn't have the path _before_ `sqlite:`... it should be: `sqlite:/full/path/to/database.sqlite`

Comment: You should var_dump your variables and check what they actually contain.

Comment: I have done what you said magnus and I get this: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file in C:\wamp64\www\CheekyIT\Test\sqlite.php

Comment: Is the database folder writable (for the user that runs PHP)?

Comment: It is in the right location, also I am assuming that I would need to put in the password and DBname within the connection string.

Comment: I have given everyone rights to the folder that the database is placed in and still no luck :/

Answer (score 1):

What you get from your magical ini file would look something like:

```
C:\wamp64\www\sqlite:/Data/DB/CheekyIT.sqlite
```

That is not correct DSN for SQLite. What you most likely want in your INI file is something like

```
host = 'sqlite:' . $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .' /Data/DB/CheekyIT.sqlite';
```

**P.S.** Marked it as "community wiki" (and thus, not gaining points for it), since @MagnusEriksson was actually the one who noticed the problem.

Comment: Thank you that didn't fix but definitely aided in the placing of the DB :).